# POCO entity without some fields (Free modeling of the entities)

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, poco

I understand that, when working with POCO entities, you should work against your model (POCO Entities). Also I supose that part of the benefits of programming against models like those should provide benefits like defining classes that don't match exactly what you see in the db.

However, there are simple operations that I don't know how to do and that I assume they should be possible. For example, in some scenarios it can be useful to change the name of one column (atribute in the entity). Also I would like to know if it's possible to generate POCO models that only represents some fields of the table that supports the object in the db.

Is there any documentation about this kind of operations?

¡Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POCO entity is just mapped class. The model in your question means mapping. The point of mapping is to define map between class and database table including mapping between properties and columns. So you can have different property and column names as long as it is correctly configured in mapping.

So if you are using EDMX file (designer) for generating the mapping you can simply change the name of property or entity and it will be reflected in your generated POCO entity. Also EDMX file will correctly update mapping. If you are using code first you must manually define mapping either through data annotations or through fluent API.

Entity should represent single data structure persisted to the database. Because of this each table can be mapped only once. Moreover EDMX designer demands that each non-nullable column without default value must be mapped to the entity. POCO generator is not tool for generating your different data views. What you are looking for is called projection. There are ways how to include mapped projections in EDMX file (`DefiningQuery` and `QueryView`) but both requires manual modifications of EDMX file and the first one also requires manual maintenance of EDMX file.

If you need to remove some properties from entity just to improve some query or because you don't need all data for some operation you can always use projection to anonymous or custom class directly in the query.

```
var query = from x in context.XEntities
            select new XView
                {
                    A = x.A,
                    B = x.B
                };
```

POCO generator is only tool for generating classes for mapped entities and projections not for generating all data related classes you will ever need.